# Using Factory Girl with Cucumber and Capybara, how do I populate forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle, capybara, factory-bot

I have this:

```
Scenario: Login
  Given a user exists with first_name: "Fred"
  When I am on the home page
  And I fill in "email" with the user: "Fred"
  And I fill in "password" with the user: "Fred"
  And I submit the form
  Then I should see "Welcome"
```

The problem is how do I get the `email` field populated with the Factory Girl-generated user's email? Email must be unique so it's defined as a sequence:

```
sequence(:email) {|n| "joeschmoe#{n}@example.com"}
```

I'm also using `pickle` but there's no step for `fill in`. How can I create the user via factory and fill out the login form with the same user's info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to this:

```
Scenario: Login
  Given a user exists with email: "fred@example.com", plain_password: "password", plain_password_confirmation: "password"
  And I am on the home page
  When I login with "fred@example.com", "password"
  And I submit the form
  Then I should see "Welcome"
```

With the following step definitions:

```
When(/^I login with "(\S+)", "(.*)"$/) do |email, password|
  fill_in 'username', :with => email
  fill_in 'plain_password', :with => password
end

# Can only be executed with Selenium or Envjs drivers
When /^I submit the form$/ do
  page.evaluate_script("document.forms[0].submit()")
end
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add you own step for it.

```
When /^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with the #{capture_model}(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |field, a, selector|

  with_scope(selector) do
    fill_in(field, :with => model!(a).send(field))
  end
end
```

Comment: I realize this, but how do I access the capture_model's attributes?

Comment: If you are using pickle then capture_model is accessible. You could see model!(a). This finds a handler.

Comment: model!(a).send(field) => finds the model with an handler and attributes. eg user_with_handle.email,  field = 'email', a = 'user with name fred', It is similar like doing User.where(:first_name => 'fred').email